# Restrict columns in a table visual that filters a card

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table visual and several cards in my report.  When a user clicks a row in that table, I don't want the card to be filtered by all of those table columns, only certain ones.  Is there anyway to accomplish this?  The card is currently populated by a measure.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the interaction between the two with "Edit Interactions" on the ribbon. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-reports-visual-interactions?tabs=powerbi-desktop

Comment: that would work but I don’t want to disable the table from filtering the card, just restrict certain columns on the table from filtering.

Comment: Disable the interaction and recreate the desired filter context with a measure. You need a sample file for further help.